# Liquibase script doesn't persist data

Tags: plsql, liquibase

I am working on a database migration in which we migrate data from 1 table to 2 other tables. For this I use a PL/SQL script. A very simplified version of the script is visible below:

```
BEGIN
  FOR foo IN (SELECT * FROM FOO) LOOP
    INSERT INTO BAR (ID, STATUS)
    VALUES (foo.ID, foo.STATUS);

    FOR foolog IN (SELECT * FROM FOO_LOG where ID = foo.ID) LOOP
      INSERT INTO BAR_LOG (ID, REV);
      VALUES (FOO_SEQ.CURRVAL, foolog.REV);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The problem is: liquibase runs the script but no data is persisted to the database, it looks as if the script doesn't run. If I introduce a typo on purpose (change a table name for example) the script fails to run so it does actually execute the script. Also, when I run the SQL manually it works as expected so it seems that the problem is related to liquibase.

Any clue of why this happens/how to solve this?

**Edit:**

Changeset that is used:

```
<changeSet id="2.4.0-03" author="bvandenberge">
    <sqlFile path="03-pie-conversion.sql"
             relativeToChangelogFile="true"
             plitStatements="false" />
    <rollback />
</changeSet>
```

Comment: have you done a `commit;` at some point? This would be needed for a transaction-based database.

Comment: @J.Chomel I tried adding a COMMIT; just before the END; but this didn't change the behaviour. Next to that, in liquibase all changesets are run in a transaction so commiting should be handled in this case.

Comment: What is this `<rollback />` used for?

Comment: That's to indicate that in case of a rollback nothing has to happen to revert the changes made by this changeSet

Comment: And if you remove it? (sorry I know not this technology).

Comment: Try to use updateSql command instead of update and check what queries are generated. Try to run them manually also.

Comment: @dbf If I run the generated queries manually they work

Comment: In presented code `FOO_SEQ.CURRVAL` may not be initialized or may return constant value

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it wasn't working and it was a really stupid mistake of myself. Nothing to do with liquibase.

I insert test data through the Intellij Oracle Console. Apparently this Console by default runs everything in a transaction but doesn't commit it automatically. So what happened is that I inserted test data through Intellij, then run the script in liquibase (which didn't find any data because the transaction in Intellij wasn't committed) and then tried to see the result in Intellij. After manually comitting the test data transaction in Intellij everything worked fine.